# Calculating a rolling 30 day average with multiple values per day

Tags: mysql, sql, rolling-computation

I have a table that looks something like this:

| city | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DC | 2020-01-01 | 10 |
| DC | 2020-01-01 | 23 |
| DC | 2020-01-02 | 43 |
| NYC | 2020-01-01 | 43 |
| NYC | 2020-01-02 | 23 |
| NYC | 2020-01-03 | 10 |

There are multiple values per city, per date. I'm having a hard time calculating the forward looking 30 day average because the condition in the rolling average should be based on the date and not based on the number of rows.
I want the output to be something like this:

| city | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DC | 2020-01-01 | 25.33 |
| DC | 2020-01-02 | 43 |
| NYC | 2020-01-01 | 25.33 |
| NYC | 2020-01-02 | 16.5 |
| NYC | 2020-01-03 | 10 |

So I **can't** do something like this:

```
AVG(value) OVER (
           PARTITION BY city, date
           ORDER BY date DESC
           ROWS BETWEEN 31 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           )
```

joining the table on itself like this:

```
SELECT t1.city, t1.date, avg(t2.values)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.city=t2.city 
    AND t2.date < DATEADD('day',31,t1.date)
    AND t2.date >= t1.date
```

**isn't** an option because it's quite large and takes forever.
How do I do this?

Comment: What does the intended output look like ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo, updated my description.

Comment: `because it's quite large and takes forever` could you show us your indexes from your table. How many rows exist in your table

Comment: There are on average 125 distinct values per city date combination. About 50 cities and 365 dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use RANGE instead of ROWS in your window frame.  But that requires ordering by a number.  So you need to do:

```
over (... order by datediff(date,'1970-01-01') asc range between 31 preceding and 1 following)
```

(Though I think you want 0 following?)